# GatsbyJS + Firebase : initializeApp is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, gatsby

I am totally stuck.

Have a setup of GatsbyJS 1 with gatsby-next and React 16 + latest Firebase 5.5.7

In develop mode everything works fine, but when I try to make a build I always get:

`WebpackError: _firebase2.default.initializeApp is not a function`

I have already tried all of the following kinds if imports, and all of them result in this error:

`import firebase from 'firebase';
// const firebase = require('firebase/app')
// import * as firebase from 'firebase';
var config = {
  ...
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);`

I have tried updating to the latest versions of all libraries. The only one I can't really update at the moment due to lots of migrations is GatsbyJS 2.0

Here is my package.json:

`"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.2.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.1",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.345.0",
    "cookieconsent": "^3.0.6",
    "firebase": "^5.5.7",
    "firebaseui": "^3.4.1",
    "fsevents": "^1.2.4",
    "gatsby": "^1.9.279",
    "gatsby-link": "^1.6.46",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-analytics": "^1.0.20",
    "gatsby-plugin-i18n": "^0.4.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^1.0.8",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-next": "^1.0.11",
    "material-ui-chip-input": "^1.0.0-beta.8",
    "paypal-checkout": "^4.0.228",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-firebaseui": "^3.1.2",
    "react-intl": "^2.4.0",
    "reactstrap": "^6.5.0"
  },`

For some time project was running fine on some older versions of libraries.

Comment: Looks like Firebase library is now using a polyfill for `fetch`, which references `window.self` that is not available during the build

Comment: I am facing the same problem with gatsby v2.

Comment: @Shoan in the end I just invested time and updated to Gatsby V2 and all the latest libraries. Working good so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long story short, Firebase now includes Fetch polyfill that references `self` internally, so it doesn't work with gatsby.

Workaround would be to not load firebase using null-loader, but then you can't reference anything firebase-related during your build time, including properties for authentication providers

Issue seems to be limited to Gatsby v1 with Firebase 5.0.+

Rolling back to older version of Firebase is not possible due to an issue with pre-gyp and node version conflicts.

Posted a bug on: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/9681